# Develop Snow Leopard apps on Mountain Lion?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, osx-mountain-lion

So, I need to develop a couple of apps for a school in my metro area, but they still currently have the 1:1 laptop program, using the old, deprecated MacBooks and still running Snow Leopard. That is totally for now, and they said maybe in the near future they will update to possibly Lion or Mountain Lion. I am now running Mountain Lion, but I want to know, if I develop a Mac app for Mountain Lion, will it still work with Snow Leopard. Also, will I maybe need to leave out the newer features, like Notification Center to allow for the app to be ported to Snow Leopard? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can choose a development target when you build your application. So building applications for Snow Leopard / Lion with Mountain Lion is no problem. BUT you can't use the new features then.

Comment: Compiling with the old SDK will certainly help as well.

Comment: Yes. But keeping both SDKs on your Mac at once is a severe pain in the back. Tried this for a couple of months and then cleaned the old one.